# Evaluate equation but ignore order of mathematical operations and parentheses

Tags: string, matlab, math

I'm trying to write a function that ignores the order of mathematical operations and parentheses. The function just evaluates operators from left to right. (for `+-*/^`)

Example 1:  `5 - 3 * 8^2` returns `256`. 
Example 2:  `4 / 2 - 1^2 + (5*3)` returns `18`.

Here's what I did:

```
function out = calc(num)
    [curNum, num] = strtok(num, '+-*/^');
    out = str2num(curNum);
    while ~isempty(num)
        sign = num(1);
        [curNum, num] = strtok(num, '+-*/^');
        switch sign
        case '+'    
            out = out + str2num(curNum);
        case'-' 
            out = out - str2num(curNum);
        case '*'
            out = out.*str2num(curNum); 
        case '/'
            out = out./str2num(curNum);
        case '^'
            out = out.^str2num(curNum);
        end
    end
end
```

My function doesn't ignore the left to right rule. How do I correct for this?

Comment: What is the output you get? It's important to include this information when you ask a question. For one thing, you don't split your string with the `^` operator in the code you have now.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your first example fails because you  are splitting the string with the `+-*/` delimiters, and you omitted the `^`. You should change this to `+-*/^` in lines 2 and 6.

Your second example fails because you aren't telling your program how to ignore the `(` and `)` characters. You should strip them before you enter the `switch` statement.

```
curNum = strrep(curNum,'(','')
curNum = strrep(curNum,')','')
switch sign
...
```

Comment: Thanks! I forgot to strip out the brackets.

Answer (score 4):

This is a way without any switch statements.

```
str = '4 / 2 - 1^2 + (5*3)'

%// get rid of spaces and brackets
str(regexp(str,'[ ()]')) = [] 

%// get numbers
[numbers, operators] = regexp(str, '\d+', 'match','split')

%// get number of numbers
n = numel(numbers);

%// reorder string with numbers closing brackets and operators
newStr = [numbers; repmat({')'},1,n); operators(2:end)];

%// add opening brackets at the beginning
newStr = [repmat('(',1,n) newStr{:}]

%// evaluate
result = eval(newStr)
```

---

```
str =  
4/2-1^2+5*3

newStr =    
((((((4)/2)-1)^2)+5)*3)

result =    
    18
```

Comment: Nice! I guess it does not matter but on the 1st line you could also use `regexprep` : `regexprep(str,'[ ()]','')`

Comment: @Benoit_11 more or less the same, isn't it?

Comment: Oh actually I had in mind that we wanted to keep the length of  `str` constant but that does not matter at all haha sorry about that